# I need to find a Laplace Transform but have problems

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Using Laplace transform find: $e^{-10t}u(t)$.

According to the Laplace table, that is equal to $1/s+10$, but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First Translation Theorem:

If $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a)$.

The Second Translation Theorem:

If $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ and $a>0$, then $\mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}F(s)$.

Using these two in conjunction, we easily deduce that $\mathcal{L}\{e^{-10t}u(t)\}=\frac{1}{s+10}$.

OR

$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-10t}u(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\left(e^{-10t}u(t)\right)dt$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-(10+s)t}u(t)dt$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-(10+s)t}u(t)dt$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-(10+s)t}dt$
$\because$  $u(t)=1$ when $t\geq0$

$=\frac{e^{-(10+s(\infty))}}{-(10+s)}-\frac{e^{-(10+s(0))}}{-(10+s)}$

$=\frac{1}{s+10}$

Comment: looks good thanks, my problem was that i did not know what to do with u(t) or how to process u(t)

Comment: Well $u(t)$ is a unit step function which is equal to $1$ when $t$ is greater or equal to $0$. Therefore you can safely replace it with $1$ as the lower limit of the integration is $0$.

Comment: what would be an example where u(t) is not 1?

Comment: $u(t-a)$ is $0$ if $t<a$ and equal to $1$ if $t\geq a$.

Comment: For example, if the problem was to evaluate $\mathcal{L}\{e^{-10t}u(t-3)\}$, we would break the integration into two intervals, first for $0$ to $3$, since $u(t-3)$ is $0$ when $t<3$, and then for $3$ to $\infty$, since $u(t-3)$ is $1$ when $t\geq 3$.

Comment: cool thanks but how would i know when is less that 0 o greater that 0 when the text book problem wont tell you that?

Comment: By understanding the definition of the step function. The step function is:

 \begin{eqnarray}
    u(t-c)  \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t \geq c  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In the case of this posed question, this was:

 \begin{eqnarray}
    u(t-0)  \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t \geq 0  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: got it, you have been a great help, thanks again